# DML statements are not supported on non-federated tables in a filtered connection

Tags: sql-server-2012

I wrote trigger on my federated database table,
after applying dml operation on it, it will give an exception like;
DML statements are not supported on non-federated tables in a filtered connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> HAVE TO MENTIONED <FEDID> TO FEDERATED DATABASE TABLE WHILE CREATING
> TABLE INTO FEDERATION AND ASSIGNED <FEDID> = <FEDID> LIKE;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AAA]') AND type in (N'U')) DROP TABLE AAA
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AAA](
            [AAAID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
            [FedID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
            [UpdateUser] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_History] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(FedID, AAAID) 
 )
FEDERATED ON (FedID= FedID)
GO
```